# PHP regular expression numeric plus one letter

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm trying to achieve validation for numeric input plus letter X or x. So far I have:

```
if(preg_match('/[^0-9xX]+$/', $data)) return 'error';
```

It correctly returns error for all cases EXCEPT a123. Have anyone idea why?

Comment: input: a123  output: not an error

Comment: `numeric input plus letter X or x` is this input considered a valid input or invalid input ?

Comment: that is a definition of validity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` at the start of regex to check if the complete string instead of sub-string.

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9xX]+$/', $data))
    return 'error';
```

Comment: use * instead of plus

Comment: @AvinashRaj That'll make the group optional, OP don't want empty content to be valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9x]+$/i', $data)){
 echo 'match';
}else{
 echo 'no match';
}
```

Its like yours, only the other way round. ^ is for the begin of the string. $ For the end of the string. So the whole string must match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]+|[xX])$/', $data)) return 'error';
```

Maybe this would be better,
it match the right case,and add `!` before match result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't got it.

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9xX]+$/', $data)) return 'error';
```

still doesn't return error when we enter 123.

I'm sorry if i make misunderstanding.

```
if(preg_match('/[0-9]xX$/', $data)) return 'error';
```

All number will be followed by xX. CMIIW.